# Why do C++ streams use char instead of unsigned char?

Tags: c++, types, stream, overflow, iostream

I've always wondered why the C++ Standard library has instantiated basic_[io]stream and all its variants using the `char` type instead of the `unsigned char` type. `char` means (depending on whether it is signed or not) you can have overflow and underflow for operations like get(), which will lead to implementation-defined value of the variables involved. Another example is when you want to output a byte, unformatted, to an ostream using its `put` function.

Any ideas?

---

**Note**: I'm still not really convinced. So if you know the definitive answer, you can still post it indeed.

Comment: I can't give a why, but I do know that the signedness of characters in GCC depends on the underlying CPU and OS.  So the convention changes from one CPU/OS to another.  I just can't say *why* it changes.

Comment: Great question! Hoping somebody give us a good reason. ACE guys use unsigned char as their ACE_Byte type ( http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/ACE-5.5.2/html/ace/Basic__Types_8h-source.html#l00272 ).

Comment: ..or why pick char from the 5 _different_ 8-bit types: `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `int8_t` and `uint8_t`. (my vote would be for the last in this list)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Possibly I've misunderstood the question, but conversion from unsigned char to char isn't unspecified, it's implementation-dependent (4.7-3 in the C++ standard).

The type of a 1-byte character in C++ is "char", not "unsigned char". This gives implementations a bit more freedom to do the best thing on the platform (for example, the standards body may have believed that there exist CPUs where signed byte arithmetic is faster than unsigned byte arithmetic, although that's speculation on my part). Also for compatibility with C. The result of removing this kind of existential uncertainty from C++ is C# ;-)

Given that the "char" type exists, I think it makes sense for the usual streams to use it even though its signedness isn't defined. So maybe your question is answered by the answer to, "why didn't C++ just define char to be unsigned?"

Comment: I thought implementation-dependent is the same as unspecified. I will correct my question and look up on the difference. thanks for telling me :)

Comment: Unspecified means the implementation can put any value it likes in there (including picking one randomly each time it happens), and not document what it does. Implementation-dependent means that the implementation must document what value it puts in there.

Comment: I heard that removing the C heritage from C++ yielded D :)

Comment: ok thanks mate. anyway i meant  if you were doing   char c = foo.get(); doSomething(c); and don't care about EOF since you know you are not at the end.

Comment: That's then an issue with converting int_type to char. You can probably rely on the implementation to choose int_type such that this conversion is sensible, even if it technically could do something weird.

Comment: Hang on, I missed something out: when converting to a signed type, if the value is representable in the target type, then the resulting value is unchanged (also 4.7.3). The return from get is defined to be either a character value or eof, so if it's not eof then the conversion is defined.

Comment: indeed, the implementation-defined'ness is only triggered for values >CHAR_MAX. that can happen in std::istringstream a("\xa4"); char c = a.get(); , if CHAR_MAX is 127 for example. but indeed the correct way is using int. but most will just use char anyway, since they don't know about this. -.-

Comment: "where signed byte arithmetic is faster than unsigned byte arithmetic" if you do any arithmetic on `((un)?signed)? char` it will be promoted to `(unsigned)? int`. Just doing `+c` is enough to trigger the promotion (this is the main use of unary +). This is a difference with C: in C any use of the value (not lvalue) of a `((un)?signed)? char` will get it promoted.

Comment: That's true, but if `a, b, c` are all unsigned char, and you do `a = b + c`, then because the result of `b+c` is converted back to unsigned char at the end, if you happen to have incredibly fast unsigned char arithmetic on the CPU then the compiler can use it. Same with `signed char`, if implementation is willing to have the same overflow behavior as the CPU. Although the values are converted to `int` as far as the defined C semantics are concerned, there's a significant class of cases where the effect of smaller arithmetic is the same and so the compiler can use it.

Comment: @xtofl: ... no, it yields 'peepee', sheez dude ... :)

Answer (score 16):

I have always understood it this way: the purpose of the `iostream` class is to read and/or write a stream of characters, which, if you think about it, are abstract entities that are only represented by the computer using a character encoding. The C++ standard makes great pains to avoid pinning down the character encoding, saying only that "Objects declared as characters (`char`) shall be large enough to store any member of the implementation's basic character set," because it doesn't need to force the "implementation basic character set" to define the C++ language;  the standard can leave the decision of *which* character encoding is used to the implementation (compiler together with an STL implementation), and just note that `char` objects represent single characters in some encoding.

An implementation writer could choose a single-octet encoding such as [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or even a double-octet encoding such as [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2). It doesn't matter. As long as a `char` object is "large enough to store any member of the implementation's basic character set" (note that this explicitly forbids [variable-length encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding)), then the implementation may even choose an encoding that represents basic Latin in a way that is incompatible with any common encoding!

It is confusing that the `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` types share "char" in their names, but it is important to keep in mind that `char` does not belong to the same family of fundamental types as `signed char` and `unsigned char`. `signed char` is in the family of signed integer types:

> There are four *signed integer types*: "signed char", "short int", "int", and "long int."

and `unsigned char` is in the family of unsigned integer types:

> For each of the signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) *unsigned integer type*: "unsigned char", "unsigned short int", "unsigned int", and "unsigned long int," ...

The one similarity between the `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` types is that "[they] occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements". Thus, you can `reinterpret_cast` from `char *` to `unsigned char *` in order to determine the numeric value of a character in the execution character set.

To answer your question, the reason why the STL uses `char` as the default type is because the standard streams are meant for reading and/or writing streams of characters, represented by `char` objects, not integers (`signed char` and `unsigned char`). The use of `char` versus the numeric value is a way of separating concerns.

Comment: `char` and `signed char` not the same? Oh wow, +1! As Scott Meyers would say, Aha! http://www.artima.com/cppsource/top_cpp_aha_moments.html

Comment: Both `istream` and `fread` (from C) read characters from streams, but `fread` uses `unsigned char` and `istream` uses `char`.

Answer (score 4):

char is for characters, unsigned char for raw bytes of data, and signed chars for, well, signed data.

Standard does not specify if signed or unsigned char will be used for the implementation of char - it is compiler-specific. It only specifies that the "char" will be "enough" to hold characters on you system - the way characters were in those days, which is, no UNICODE.

Using "char" for characters is the standard way to go. Using unsigned char is a hack, although it'll match compiler's implementation of char on most platforms.

Comment: "Using "char" for characters is the standard way to go. Using unsigned char is a hack", how is that? Streams are not only for exchanging basic characters, but also for exchanging binary data (after all, that's what `ios_base::binary` is for). Would it use `unsigned char`, we would not have to care about negative char values at all, and always get positive values back. It would seem to be so much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672587/representing-blobs-in-c#comment13846926_10672587) comment explains it well. To quote:

> signed char and unsigned char are arithmetic, integral types just like int and unsigned int. On the other hand, char is expressly intended to be the "I/O" type that represents some opaque, system-specific fundamental unit of data on your platform. I would use them in this spirit.