# const unsigned char * to std::string

Tags: c++, std

sqlite3_column_text returns a const unsigned char*, how do I convert this to a std::string? I've tried std::string(), but I get an error.

Code:

```
temp_doc.uuid = std::string(sqlite3_column_text(this->stmts.read_documents, 0));
```

Error:

```
1>.\storage_manager.cpp(109) : error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const unsigned char *' to 'std::string'
1>        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You could try:

```
temp_doc.uuid = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(
      sqlite3_column_text(this->stmts.read_documents, 0)
  ));
```

While `std::string` could have a constructor that takes `const unsigned char*`, apparently it does not.

Why not, then? You could have a look at this somewhat related question: [Why do C++ streams use char instead of unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277655/why-do-c-streams-use-char-instead-of-unsigned-char)

Comment: +1. although, I think you should make that "const char *" inside your angle brackets.  You don't want to be trying to cast away the const-ness (which it may not even allow).

Comment: I get this error:
1>.\storage_manager.cpp(109) : error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const unsigned char *' to 'const char *'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: Uh-oh. Well, maybe you need reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast, then?

Comment: Since I'm quite sure that it will work, I'll edit the answer too.

Comment: You mean reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpretcast

Answer (score 21):

On the off-chance you actually want a string of unsigned characters, you could create your own type:

```
typedef std::basic_string <unsigned char> ustring;
```

You should then be able to say things like:

```
ustring s = sqlite3_column_text(this->stmts.read_documents, 0);
```

Answer (score 20):

The reason people typically use an (unsigned char *) type is to indicate that the data is binary and not plain ASCII text.  I know libxml does this, and from the looks of it, sqlite is doing the same thing.

The data you're getting back from the sqlite call is probably UTF-8 encoded Unicode text.  While a reinterpret_cast may appear to work, if someone ever stores text in the field that is not plain ASCII, your program probably won't be well-behaved.

The std::string class isn't designed with Unicode in mind, so if you ask for the length() of a string, you'll get the number of bytes, which, in UTF-8, is not necessarily the same thing as the number of characters.

Short answer: the simple cast may work, if you're certain the data is just ASCII.  If it can be any UTF-8 data, then you need to handle encoding/decoding in a smarter way.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with the std:: library?

Comment: Not that I know of.  The standard approach is to use a 3rd party library, for example: http://site.icu-project.org/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with sqlite3_column_text, but one thing you may want to do is when you call the std:string constructor, you'll want to cast to (const char*). I believe that it should have a constructor for that type.

However, it is odd that this sqlite function is return an unsigned char*, is it returning a Pascal string (first char is the length of the string)? If so, then you'll have to create the std::string with the bytes and the length.

Comment: No, they are null terminated.

Answer (score 3):

if temp_doc.uuid is a std::string try :

```
temp_doc.uuid = static_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(this->stmts.read_documents, 0));
```

Comment: It is a std::string, and trying out your method gives me:

1>.\storage_manager.cpp(109) : error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const unsigned char *' to 'const char *'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
temp_doc.uuid = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(this->stmts.read_documents, 0)));
```

Comment: I saw someone already posted the answer , I started to write this answer before the other was posted(was checking that the answer is correct in VS)

Comment: I am only saying it so I won't think I copy answers

Comment: I am only saying it so you won't think I copy answers

Comment: const char* and const unsigned char* are not the same type. string constructor expect const char* and therefor a cast is needed

Answer (score 2):

You can't construct a `std::string` from c`onst unsigned char*` -- you have to cast it to `const char*` first:

```
temp_doc.uuid = std::string( reinterpret_cast< const char* >(
  sqlite3_column_text(this->stmts.read_documents, 0) ) );
```

Comment: sorry, have to use reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but this example here seems much simpler:

```
string name = (const char*) (sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
```

Comment: Don't use C cast in C++, it's a bad practice. A reinterpret_cast will show your intention more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

An old but important question, if you have to preserve the full information in the unsigned char sequence. In my opinion that is with reinterpret_cast not the case. I found an interesting solution under [converting string to vector](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/626633-convert-std-string-std-vector-unsigned-char-vice-versa)
which I modified to

```
basic_string<unsigned char> temp = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
string firstItem( temp.begin(), temp.end() );
```

Since I am programming for gtkmm, you can realize the conversion into a Glib::ustring with

```
basic_string<unsigned char> temp = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
Glib::ustring firstItem = string( temp.begin(), temp.end() );
```