# Copying non null-terminated unsigned char array to std::string

Tags: c++, string, copy, null-terminated, arrays

If the array was *null-terminated* this would be pretty straight forward:

```
unsigned char u_array[4] = { 'a', 's', 'd', '\0' };
std::string str = reinterpret_cast<char*>(u_array);
std::cout << "-> " << str << std::endl;
```

However, I wonder what is the most appropriate way to copy a **non null-terminated** unsigned char array, like the following:

```
unsigned char u_array[4] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f' };
```

into a `std::string`.

Is there any way to do it without iterating over the *unsigned char array*?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`std::string` has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a pair of iterators and `unsigned char` can be converted (in an implementation defined manner) to `char` so this works. There is no need for a `reinterpret_cast`.

```
unsigned char u_array[4] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f' };

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str( u_array, u_array + sizeof u_array / sizeof u_array[0] );
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course an "array size" template function is more robust than the `sizeof` calculation.

Comment: Converting `unsigned char *` into  `char *` here, you have to do `reinterpret_cast<const char *>`.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: But I don't want to do that conversion.

Comment: @Charles: Then your code won't compile unless you change default type for char to unsigned in compiler's settings ;)

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: It does compile :)

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: `unsigned char*` satisfies the requirements for an input iterator. My code compiles and works just fine.

Comment: @Charles, stop using buggy compilers. Constructor signature you need to call is `std::string (const char *, size_t)`, as `unsigned` is not converted to `signed` implicitly, passing `unsigned char *` will introduce ambiguity. Check with proper compiler, or see, for example, - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804123/const-unsigned-char-to-stdstring

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I don't _need_ to call that constructor, I'm quite happy with this constructor: `template<class InputIterator> basic_string(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, const Allocator& a = Allocator());`

Comment: @Charles: Oh, I must be blind. Of course, you use two pointers here. Didn't notice `u_array + ` in second argument. My bad. +1 for your answer then.

Comment: FYI, the division by `sizeof u_char[0]` is completely redundant. This size is *guaranteed* by the standard to be equal to the size of `char`, which is 1 by definition.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. I was in two minds about taking it out and leaving it in. Some people are making the valid argument elsewhere that it's robust against a change in type of `u_char` but it's marginal either way IMHO.

Comment: @Konrad: I believe Charles chose to show the general code, so as not to mislead readers into just doing a `sizeof` for e.g. `wchar_t`.

Comment: Or you can simply replace the second parameter with `std::end(u_array)` (C++0x)

Answer (score 28):

Well, apparently **std::string** has a **constructor** that could be used in this case:

```
std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(u_array), 4);
```

Comment: More of ideological thought, but it would be nicer not to cast away the constness of array. Plus, taking size of it instead of hard-coding error-prone `4`.

Answer (score 8):

When constructing a string without specifying its size, constructor will iterate over a a character array and look for null-terminator, which is `'\0'` character. If you don't have that character, you have to specify length explicitly, for example:

```
// --*-- C++ --*--

#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int
main ()
{
    unsigned char u_array[4] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f' };
    std::string str (reinterpret_cast<const char *> (u_array),
                     sizeof (u_array) / sizeof (u_array[0]));
    std::cout << "-> " << str << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

std::string has a method named assign. You can use a char * and a size.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/

Comment: It also has a constructor that takes char pointer and size. In those cases when you don't have a string instance yet, it will make sense to use constructor.

Comment: The problem with this situation is you then don't know how many bytes your string takes up, and whether or not doing .c_str() will give you a valid c string or not.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
std::string s(u_array, u_array+sizeof(u_array)/sizeof(u_array[0]));
```

Comment: u_array is of type unsigned char, and `std::string`'s constructor take `const char *`, so this won't even compile.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: No, as i checked it should be just fine.

Comment: @Dave, default type for char is signed, not unsigned, and it cannot  implicitly convert one into another. Your compiler either treating `char` as `unsigned` or it is buggy. In any case, generic solution should not rely on these specifics and use explicit conversion. You can check this with Comeau online or something, it doesn't work.

Comment: `/4` ? The array is an array of `unsigned char`. Why is it relevant that an `int` is 4 bytes (even if this assumption happens to be correct)?

Comment: @VladLazarenko: An `unsigned char` _can_ be converted to a `char`, they are both integral types (e.g. `char x = (unsigned char)10;`) The result is implementation-defined if the value of the `unsigned char` is not expressible in a `char` but it is a valid conversion.

Comment: @Charles: of course they can be converted. But they cannot be converted implicitly. Your compiler must have `char` as `unsigned` by default, that makes sense, but is non standard, I guess. Or it must be very smart to look into compile-time constant array and decide that it can be converted into array with signed values.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Any integer type can be converted to any other integer type: 4.7 [conv.integral] . This includes `unsigned char` and `char`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `std::string` constructor:

```
string ( const char * s, size_t n );
```

so in your example:

```
std::string str(u_array, 4);
```

Comment: You can make it better by doing `sizeof (u_array)`. Or even better - `sizeof (u_array) / sizeof(u_array[0])`, which will work for data types who`s size is greater than 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a character pointer pointing to the first character, and another pointing to one-past-the-last, and construct using those two pointers as iterators. Thus:

```
std::string str(&u_array[0], &u_array[0] + 4);
```

Comment: This is error prone as size of array can change, and you might easily forget to replace your `4` with a new value. Plus, there is no point in doing `&u_array[0]`, it is equivalent of just `u_array`, which is much less typing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a still a problem when the string *itself* contains a null character and you try to subsequently print the string:

```
char c_array[4] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 0 };

std::string toto(array,4);
cout << toto << endl;  //outputs a 3 chars and a NULL char
```

However....

```
cout << toto.c_str() << endl; //will only print 3 chars.
```

Its times like these when you just want to ditch cuteness and use bare C.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question was how to "copy a non null-terminated `unsigned char` array [...] into a `std::string`", I note that in the given example that string is only used as an input to `std::cout`.

In that case, of course you can avoid the string altogether and just do

```
std::cout.write(u_array, sizeof u_array);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

which I think may solve the problem the OP was *trying* to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
std::string str;
str.resize(4);
std::copy(u_array, u_array+4, str.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

std::string has a constructor taking an array of char and a length.

```
unsigned char u_array[4] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f' };
std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(u_array), sizeo(u_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ew, why the cast?

```
 std::string str(u_array, u_array + sizeof(u_array));
```

Done.