# Why doesn't my copy constructor work?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, stdstring

This is probably a no-brainer, but I'm a little stumped. I've had some trouble with my [vectors not behaving nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297093/whys-my-vector-element-all-garbage), and now it looks like I've found the culprit. Here's a watered down version of my `Player` class.

```
class Player {
private:
    std::string _firstName;
    std::string _lastName;
public:
    Player(std::string firstName, std::string lastName) {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
    };
    Player(const Player& otherPlayer) {
        _firstName = otherPlayer._firstName.c_str();
        _lastName = otherPlayer._lastName.c_str();
        std::cout << "Created " << _firstName << " " << _lastName << std::endl; // Why doesn't _firstName and _lastName contain anything?
    };
    std::string GetName() { return _firstName + " " + _lastName; };
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Player player1 = Player("Bill", "Clinton");
    Player player2 = Player(player1);

    std::cout << "Player: " << player2.GetName() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is a meager `Player:`. I'm not sure why my copy constructor doesn't do what I want it to do, in particular in light of advice such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4751467/182048) (Zac Howland's comment accounts for the `c_str();`-part). Am I violating [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/182048) (which, btw, I still haven't totally gotten my head around)? I'd be really grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: @Zak Howland's comments are wrong.  He's describing how things used to work ~10 years ago, but (A) nowdays `std::string::operator=` is required to do a deep copy, and (B) it was always required to _act like_ a deep copy.

Comment: [I added `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>`](http://ideone.com/DjrNcp)

Comment: You don't actually need the copy constructor at all - the default one will do the right thing. If you do have it, you don't need the calls to `c_str()` (they just make it less robust), and you should initialise the members rather than assigning to them. But despite that I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work as it stands. What output do you get?

Comment: it (*cough*) works on my machine.

Comment: [It works fine on ideone.](http://ideone.com/0lXVPB)

Comment: @Mooing Duck - The requirement to do a deep copy only changed with C++11.  Previously, it was up to the implementer.

Comment: @Derek yeah, that was just sloppy on my part. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks for pointing out these subtleties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me : http://ideone.com/aenViu

I just addded :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

But there is something I don't understand :

```
_firstName = otherPlayer._firstName.c_str();
_lastName = otherPlayer._lastName.c_str();
```

Why the `.c_str()` ? You convert the `string` to `char*` to assign it to a new `string`?

*EDIT :* From the comment, Zac Howland pointed : *"Prior to C++11, if you wanted to ensure your string was copied (instead of reference counted), you had to use the `c_str()` method to force it to copy the string. The new standard eliminates that, but if he's using an older compiler, or one that hasn't fully implemented C++11 yet, it will ensure a deep copy."*

Just do :

```
_firstName = otherPlayer._firstName;
_lastName = otherPlayer._lastName;
```

And, do you really need this copy constructor ? The default would do what you want I think...

---

Also, instead of assigning the members :

```
Player(std::string firstName, std::string lastName) {
    _firstName = firstName;
    _lastName = lastName;
}
```

use the *member-initialization-list* instead :

```
Player(std::string firstName, std::string lastName) :
    _firstName( std::move(firstName) ),
    _lastName( std::move(lastName) )
{}
```

In the first case the string's default constructor is called and then string's copy-assignment operator, there could definitely be (minor) efficiency losses compared to the second case, which directly calls the copy-constructor.

Last thing, when it is possible, does not pass values as method arguments, pass references and even const references when they don't need to be modified :

```
Player( const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName )
//      ^^^^^            ^            ^^^^^            ^
    : _firstName( firstName )  // no move here, since args are constant references
    , _lastName( lastName )
{}
```

---

Working [live example](http://ideone.com/aenViu) of all the modifications.

Comment: Prior to C++11, if you wanted to ensure your string was copied (instead of reference counted), you had to use the c_str() method to force it to copy the string.  The new standard eliminates that, but if he's using an older compiler, or one that hasn't fully implemented C++11 yet, it will ensure a deep copy.

Comment: @ZacHowland Oh That's right ! I will put that in the answer ! Thank you for pointing this out !

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud I guess, I provoked you with my deleted (I thought, it was irrelevant after I saw you use `std::move()`) comment to make an edit about using `const &`. But now, can you explain, please, the reason for `std::move()` in your constructor with `const &`?

Comment: @Petr:  `std::move` is in the constructor without the `const &`.  Since copies will already be made (when they are passed-by-copy), the `move` operation just allows the Player instance to take ownership of those copies (instead of creating yet another copy).

Comment: @PetrBudnik Thank you for pointing this out. Was time for me to go to bed ;) Thank you Zac for editing my post !

Comment: @ZacHowland I understand why `std::move` is in constructor with values. I was asking about one with `const &`. Which was edited.

Comment: Just to make myself clear - using `std::move` on `const &` without `const_cast` will not make compiler use move-constructor, it will still use copy-constructor (which we want). But this might be a misleading construction (to the programmer), so I thought it's better to remove it.

Comment: So I figured it out. It would've worked for me too, if I didn't link in another 'class Player' which got picked up by the compiler (which I still don't get, since the 'Player.h' was not included in my main file). Anyways: thanks to everyone, and in particular @PierreFourgeaud for a lengthy answer! :)