# How to represent unsigned char values as hexadecimal string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, unsigned-char

I want to convert an unsigned char arrays content to a hexadecimal string representation.
Can anyone help with a function or a way out?

```
unsigned char codeslink[5] ={ 0x33, 0x74, 0x74, 0x73, 0x72};
std::string my_std_string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(codeslink), 5);
std::string my_std_string((const char *)codeslinks);
```

I want to get a return values `3374747372` as char or string.

**update:**
This is the function i came up with using `@πάνταῥεῖ:` answer  i want to make it better and make it robust to handle `unsigned char` like `0x00,0x04,0x00,0x11` of various length size.

```
std::string Return_Uchar_To_String(unsigned char uns_char, size_t uns_char_len)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0');
        for(size_t i = 0; i < uns_char_len; ++i)
        {
            oss << (unsigned int)uns_char[i];
        }


        return oss.str();
    }
```

Comment: `std::string my_std_string = std::to_string(3374747372);`?

Comment: That's not done through casting.

Comment: That is not going to work: `0x33 != "33"`.  Otherwise this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691608/copying-non-null-terminated-unsigned-char-array-to-stdstring

Comment: @R_Kapp `std::string my_std_string = std::to_string(codeslink);` dont understand how you mean? @πάντα ῥεῖ  how is it best done? @NatanOliver that didnt work for me either

Comment: @R_Kapp's comment is nonsense, regarding hex values.

Comment: @DavidoLLP I wrote an answer for what you need.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He said he wanted a specific return value as a string; maybe I'm misunderstanding the question (most likely so), but just use `std::to_string` and make it one? Or better yet, `std::string my_std_string = "3374747372";`?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should make a new question and ask it there (provided it meets the standards of this site). Don't ask new questions on an old question that already has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get a return values `3374747372` as char or string.

Casting doesn't work in this case.

You can use text formatting IO to get a hex string representation of the arrays content:

```
unsigned char codeslink[5] ={ 0x33, 0x74, 0x74, 0x73, 0x72};
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    oss << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)codeslink[i];
}
std::string result = oss.str();
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6da548a7586dc61)

Comment: kudos for editing the title of the post, i have posted a function i derived form it ot make it flexible for various unsigned char size can you look at the function and help me refactor it to be robust?

Comment: @DavidoLLP You seem to have a small mistake in your function signature: `std::string Return_Uchar_To_String(unsigned char uns_char, size_t uns_char_len)` should be `std::string Return_Uchar_To_String(const unsigned char* uns_char, size_t uns_char_len)`, Otherwise it looks OK and will be _robust_.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  thanks for the update i tried my function with this value `unsigned char codeslink[4] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x11 };` i got this `000211` instead of `00000211` function is ` Return_Uchar_To_String(codeslink, sizeof(codeslink));` similary with calls like `unsigned char codeslink[4] = { 0x10, 0x00, 0x02, 0x11 };` any thoughts, is that a bug?

Comment: @DavidoLLP Sorry, I forgot that `setw()` isn't sticky to the stream, but just changes the behavior for the next output field.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  no offense taken, you have being helpful thanks