# How to convert LPBYTE to string

Tags: c++, string, lpbyte

```
LPBYTE buffer = (LPBYTE)calloc(1024, sizeof(char));
std::string res;
```

I want something like:

```
res = buffer;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying non null-terminated unsigned char array to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691608/copying-non-null-terminated-unsigned-char-array-to-stdstring)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are you looking for `std::string` to own the buffer? Or to hold a copy of its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) constructor (number 6 in the link) that uses iterators to copy the buffer into a string:

```
std::string res(buffer, buffer + 1024);
```

Note that there is no conversion other than the `unsigned char`s in your `buffer` being converted to `char`s in the `std::string`.

Comment: Note that the buffer is copied as-is without any conversion from possibly non-textual format. This may or might not be was intended by "convert to string".

Comment: @eerorika True. Added a note about that.