# Making sense of stacktrace

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, gnu, boost-stacktrace

I have been trying to debug an issue with my service which results in a segmentation fault. I do not have access to the production server, so I have handled the SIGSEGV signal in my service and printed the stacktrace in the Log files. Following is the stacktrace when the service crashes

```
0# 0x00000000005054DA in ./afiniti_lookup
1# 0x00007F2BBB74A400 in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
2# 0x00007F2BBB86F9BD in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
3# 0x000000000041BB52 in ./afiniti_lookup
4# std::string::_M_move(char*, char const*, unsigned long) in ./afiniti_lookup
5# std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) in ./afiniti_lookup
6# std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) in ./afiniti_lookup
7# std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long) in ./afiniti_lookup
8# std::string::assign(char const*) in ./afiniti_lookup
9# std::string::operator=(char const*) in ./afiniti_lookup
10# 0x000000000061E8E9 in ./afiniti_lookup
11# 0x0000000000620200 in ./afiniti_lookup
12# 0x000000000055B586 in ./afiniti_lookup
13# 0x00000000004F2BAC in ./afiniti_lookup
14# 0x00000000004F0715 in ./afiniti_lookup
15# 0x000000000051CDBF in ./afiniti_lookup
16# 0x0000000000529869 in ./afiniti_lookup
17# 0x0000000000464968 in ./afiniti_lookup
18# 0x0000000000461369 in ./afiniti_lookup
19# 0x0000000000460D6E in ./afiniti_lookup
20# 0x0000000000460086 in ./afiniti_lookup
21# 0x000000000045FD36 in ./afiniti_lookup
22# 0x000000000046CAB4 in ./afiniti_lookup
23# 0x000000000046B4F6 in ./afiniti_lookup
24# 0x000000000046FF13 in ./afiniti_lookup
25# 0x000000000046FE65 in ./afiniti_lookup
26# 0x000000000046FCDA in ./afiniti_lookup
27# 0x00007F2BBCE5038F in /opt/lib64/libcpprest.so.2.10
28# 0x00007F2BBEDCAEA5 in /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0\n29# clone in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
```

However, this trace is not of much use as I cannot pinpoint the location in my code where the issue is occurring. Can somebody help me better understand and inspect this stacktrace?

Comment: Wild guess: you're assigning a null `char const *` to a string somewhere.

Comment: Well, you do have some access to production server, since you got the logs. Can you get a `core` file? Is the bug reproducible? Worst case, you could try disassembling code around SIGSEGV.

Comment: Searching for `_M_mutate` I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904221/assigning-unsigned-char-buffer-to-a-string), which might be the same problem you have. That is, you are creating an `std::string` somewhere from a `const char*` which is not null-terminated. Therefore, you need to use `std::string` constructor specifying the number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody help me better understand and inspect this stacktrace?

It looks like you have a partially-stripped executable in production.

You *should* have an unstripped copy (which was produced by linking your executable). If you don't, you'll need to change your ways, and save a copy before you `strip`.

With an unstripped copy, you can make sense of your stack trace like so:

```
addr2line -fe afiniti_lookup.unstripped 0x61E8E9 0x620200 0x55B586 ...
```

Here is example output:

```
cat foo.c

int foo() { int *ip = 0; return *ip; }
int bar() { return foo(); }
int zoo() { return bar(); }
int main() { return zoo(); }
```

Compile this with debug info: `gcc -g foo.c` (produces `a.out`).
Strip the binary for "production": `strip --strip=all a.out -o b.out`.

Run the `b.out` under GDB to simulate production stack trace:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/b.out

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401112 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000401112 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000401124 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000401134 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000401144 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007ffff7dfbcca in __libc_start_main (main=0x401136, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdc98, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdc88) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#5  0x000000000040104a in ?? ()
```

Now use `addr2line` on the *unstripped* binary to make sense of the stack trace above:

```
addr2line -fe a.out 0x0000000000401112 0x0000000000401124 0x0000000000401134 0x0000000000401144
foo
/tmp/foo.c:1
bar
/tmp/foo.c:2
zoo
/tmp/foo.c:3
main
/tmp/foo.c:4
```

P.S. For real production use, ideally you would compile your binary with `gcc -O2 -g ...`, so you have *full* debug info, and then `strip` the binary (but keep a full-debug copy). That way you can fairly easily debug core dumps from production with access to functions, files, lines and variables.