# How to create a sqlite3_value for testing with gtest

Tags: c++, sqlite, googletest

Im writing a wrapper class for sqlite3 just 4 fun and learning c++11 and gtest. Im testing my wrapper with gtest. In one specific test case i need a sqlite3_value object for comparing my function result. I have no idea how i can create a sqlite3_value object from scratch. I searched the internet and found this solution:

```
sqlite3 *tmpDB;
sqlite3_open_v2(":memory", &tmpDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, 0);
sqlite3_stmt *tmpStmt = nullptr;

sqlite3_prepare_v2(tmpDB, "SELECT ?;", 9, &tmpStmt, nullptr);
sqlite3_bind_text(tmpStmt, 0, "paul", 4, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
int res = sqlite3_step(tmpStmt);
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_value_text(sqlite3_column_value(tmpStmt, 0)))); /*Here throws the exception below*/
sqlite3_finalize(tmpStmt);
```

The following exception will be thrown while string construction before the sqlite3_finalize() is called:

`C++ exception with description "basic_string::_M_construct null not valid" thrown in the test body`.

I tried a solution from stack overflow:
[Stack Overflow std::basic_string solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804123/const-unsigned-char-to-stdstring)
but i got the same exception.

Im not sure that it is possible to build a sqlite3_value from scratch. Is the way how i try to "build" a sqlite3_value the right one?

Maybe i have to think about to use an other type as std::string. I read about some reasons like std::string do not support text witch is not plain ACSII. Is that right?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: The exception you cite means that you passed a `nullptr` to the `std::string` constructor. This is forbidden. The reason you pass a null pointer is that you use `sqlite3_value_text` on a value that does not represent a STRING value. This again is caused by the failure of the query.

There are many good aspects in the current revision of the answer by CL. Let's start with the most important advice:

> Also, you must check the return values of all functions for errors.

You said you are using Google Test, so let's use the EXPECT_EQ statement to find out whether the functions indeed return the value you expected. Here is a complete minimal example with added error checking:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(void)
{
  sqlite3 *tmpDB;
  EXPECT_EQ(SQLITE_OK, sqlite3_open_v2(":memory", &tmpDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, 0));
  sqlite3_stmt *tmpStmt = nullptr;

  EXPECT_EQ(SQLITE_OK, sqlite3_prepare_v2(tmpDB, "SELECT ?;", 9, &tmpStmt, nullptr));
  EXPECT_EQ(SQLITE_OK, sqlite3_bind_text(tmpStmt, 0, "paul", 4, SQLITE_TRANSIENT));
  int res = sqlite3_step(tmpStmt);
  EXPECT_EQ(SQLITE_ROW, res);
  std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_value_text(sqlite3_column_value(tmpStmt, 0))));
  EXPECT_EQ(SQLITE_OK, sqlite3_finalize(tmpStmt));
}
```

This will output a lot of expectation failures. Oops! The first expectation failure is sqlite_open returning 14 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN). You can find the reason for that by carefully reading the answer given by CL, in fact, carefully reading the first sentence ought to be enough.

Having fixed that, the EXPECT_EQ on sqlite3_bind_text fails with error code 25 (SQLITE_RANGE). Read the documentation of sqlite3_bind_text, especially the first two sentences of the paragraph describing the second parameter to find out what's wrong in this call.

Having fixed this, too, I no longer get an exception or any expectation failures.

Answer (score 0):

The name of an in-memory database is not `:memory` but `:memory:`.

The last parameter of [sqlite3_bind_text()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) must not be NULL.

But your problem is that the query is never executed.

Furthermore, as shown in the [sqlite3_column_value() documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html):

> the pointers returned are valid until … sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called.

You would have to extract the text before finalizing the statement.
Alternatively, keep the statement object around in your `DataObject`.

Also, you must check the return values of all functions for errors.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I debugged it again. I think my problem is not the validity of the pointer. I copy the text right after the sqlite3_bind_text function as shown above into a std::sting. And at this point:

{case SQLITE_TEXT:
{
    dataObj_.setText(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_value_text(value)));
    break;
}//end SQLITE_TEXT}

the exception is thrown.

I tried also to add "SQLITE_TRANSIENT" to the bind function bot it helps nothing.

Comment: Your are not copying the text; you are copying a pointer to the internal `sqlite3_value` object.

Comment: Same exception here:

`sqlite3 *tmpDB;
 sqlite3_open_v2(":memory", &tmpDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, 0);
sqlite3_stmt *tmpStmt = nullptr;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(tmpDB, "SELECT ?;", 9, &tmpStmt, nullptr);
sqlite3_bind_text(tmpStmt, 0, "paul", 4, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (sqlite3_value_text(sqlite3_column_value(tmpStmt, 0))));`

My problem is, that i dont understand why the statement is`t executed?
What must i do to get a valid std::string without a exception??

Comment: You must execute the query (with [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)). And, to repeat myself, you must get the string before finalizing the statement.

Comment: That is what i do. I updated my question above for better understanding. The exception throws every time before the sqlite3_finalize() is called. The next what i don't understand is the result of the sqlite3_step() = 21 (SQLITE_MISUSE). Any think must be wrong. Maybe it is not possible to use sqlite how i do.