# C-style array vs std::array for library interface

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to write a library with an interface that provide a read function.
C-style array is error prone but allow to pass a buffer of any size.
C++ array are safer but impose to be constructed with a size.

```
// interface.h

// C-style array
int read (std::uint8_t* buf, size_t len);

// C++ array
int read (std::array<std::uint8_t, 16>& buff)
```

How can I have the best of both worlds?

I was thinking about function template but it does not seems practical for a library interface.

```
template <size_t N>
int read (std::array<std::uint8_t, N>& buf);
```

**EDIT**
`std::vector` could be a good candidate but if we consider that `char*` and `std::array` do not have dynamic allocation.

**EDIT** I like a lot the solution with `gsl::span`. I am stuck with C++14 so no `std::span`. I don't know if using a third library (gsl) will be an issue/allow.

**EDIT** I did not think that using `char` over another type could have some influence on the answer, so to be clearer it is to manipulate bytes. I change `char` to `std::uint8_t`

**EDIT** Since C++11 guarantee that a return `std::vector` will moved and not copied, returning `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` is acceptable.

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> read();
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`?

Comment: If `N` would be a compile time constant, and you don't care about publishing the implementation of `read`, and you don't need your API to be C compatible, then there's nothing wrong with the templated version.

Comment: How about [`gsl::span`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/2486888)?

Comment: It's hard to say with the limited information on what you're doing, but you might consider iterator-based interface that doesn't require a specific container.

Comment: `std::vector` has dynamic allocation but `char*` or `std::array` don't.

Comment: The `C-Style` array (`char *`) would allow for dynamic allocation.. they just need to pass in the size. The `std::array` would be fixed size only. With the `C-Style` array, you get the best of both worlds but also the danger of a bad developer.. The developer using your library would be able to choose whether or not they want their own memory dynamically allocated or static. With `std::array`, they don't have a choice. With `std::vector` it will always be dynamic, but you'd get the safety of `std::array`. I personally prefer `C-Style` array. Let the developer worry about their own safety.

Comment: @boutboutnico how would you know whether the `char*` points to dynamic memory?

Comment: @Quentin Well you cannot know but you can have static allocation

Comment: @NickyC `gsl::span` is a nice thing, but I would be very careful making my library dependent on GSL just because of this issue. Hopefully, once there will be `std::span`...

Comment: Is the `char` intentional (indicating text), or do you really mean to write `std::byte` or `unsigned char` (indicating bytes)?

Comment: The first version is fine and doesn't constraint you to a C array at all.

Comment: This question is too broad because you tell us too little about your library. Like, should it be compatible with C, is it used only in your own projects, should it be a DLL, and so on. Chances are that you can just use a templated function and that *"it does not seems practical for a library interface"* is just a wrong feeling.

Answer (score 6):

You could do what the standard library does: **Use a pair of [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).**

```
template <typename Iter> int read(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    // Some static assets to make sure `Iter` is actually a proper iterator type
}
```

It gives you the best of both worlds: Slightly better safety and ability to read into an arbitrary part of a buffer. Also it allows you to read into non-continguous containers.

Comment: The level of 'safety' is the same as with dynamic arrays.

Comment: Also consider using iterator traits to restrict the type of iterator, depending on the functionality it is given.

Comment: read function with a set of iterators is a very unusual. Care to explain the benefits over standard void* and size?

Comment: @SergeyA It's not *that* much safer. But at least it's protected against silly bugs like `void *buf = blah; int status = read(&buf, buf_len);`.

Comment: You don't need static_asserts in there. Just do the usual `begin++` and `begin != end`. If those won't work, the compiler will tell you. If you want to do random reads, then it might be useful to have the static_asserts and some messages, just so the user is not confused when compiling your library.

Comment: @smac89 `static_assert` gives you a better description of the problem though. I would prefer getting *"static_assert: `Iter` is not a valid %iterator_category% iterator"* instead of tons of cryptic error messages.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, true, true, I just updated my comment to that effect.

Comment: @SergeyA, I don't find it unusual to have a read function use iterators. When you think of SRP (Single responsibility principle), a function which reads should just do that, and not have to worry about the size of the buffer given to it to read from. Short of re-writing the _gets()_ function from C's long lost past, using iterators is a much cleaner approach

Comment: @smac89 I will agree with you if you show me any `read` function from any wide-used APIs which takes a pair of iterators.

Comment: @SergeyA I suggest that [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate), in a way, might fulfill that requirement. It "reads" values from the generator into the range of iterators provided.

Comment: @SergeyA, as long as we are not bound to functions called **read**, just take a look at any function in `std::algorithm`, they all take a pair of iterators when it comes to reading from a container. I also maintain a csv library (currently in progress) which makes extensive use of `Reader` objects, which take a pair of iterators (`istream_iterator`, std::begin(container) iterators, whatev_iter). I also program mainly in Java, and the `Stream` api is based on iterators - albeit slightly different from std::iterators, but the point is, none of them use **size** to determine when to stop reading.

Comment: @smac89 I believe, your Java experience is not very relevant here. And I think, there is a reason why the function is called read.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I have the best of the two world ?

By using `std::vector`:

- Like `std::array`s: It is safer than C-arrays.
- Like C-arrays: It allows you to work with functions that must be able take an array of arbitrary size.

**EDIT**: `std::vector` does not necessarily imply *dynamic allocation* (as in *dynamic storage duration*). That depends on the *allocator* used. You can still provide a user-specified [stack allocator](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html).

Answer (score 1):

I will go against the grain and say that for `read`-type function taking `void*` pointer and size are likely the best option. This is the approach taken with any unformatted read functions around the world.

Comment: I'd like to enforce type-safety

Comment: How does `char*` enforce the type-safety?

Comment: @SergeyA: Because the OP is handling text. If it were bytes it would be `std::byte`, or `unsigned char`. That's what the code communicates to humans, anyway.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf last time I checked, `std::*stream` unformatted read functions were taking `char*` (to be exact, `char_type` which is `char*` in default stream).

Comment: The streams are mainly about text, and they're documented, and they have a history back to old C. `std::byte` made it into C++17.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf unsigned char was known even back than, and read/write are *unformatted* input/output functions, and as such has nothing to do with text.

Comment: @SergeyA: Uhm. When I mentioned old C it was mostly about the coding practice back then: favoring terseness, primarily communicating to the compiler. Today terseness is not so extremely highly valued, while communicating to humans (maintainers, users, future self) is. Re unformatted that doesn't mean binary, it just means not formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `gsl::span`, which was meant for the purpose of eliminating pointer and length parameter pairs for a sequence of contiguous objects? Something like this would work:

```
int read(gsl::span<uint8_t> buf)
{
    for (auto& elem : buf)
    {
        // Do whatever with elem
    }
}
```

The only problem is that unfortunately, `gsl::span` is not part of C++ standard (Maybe  it might be in [C++20](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0122r5.pdf)), and installing it would require a library such as [GSL-lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite)

[Here](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md) are more details about `span`, from Herb Sutter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care about the type of the underlying container ?

```
template<typename Iterator>
int read_n(Iterator begin, size_t len);
```

Assuming this function returns the number of elements read, i would change the return type to `size_t` as well.

```
char *dyn = new char[20];
char stat[20];
std::vector<char> vec(20);
read(dyn, 20);
read(stat 20);
read(vec.begin(), 20);
```

Comment: Taking an iterator and a size is very unusual in c++. The implementaiton will almost certainly need to calculate the end iterator anyway. The problem gets worse with non-random access iterators, if it's desirable to support them.

Comment: Indeed, But in fact i was thinking about ContiguousIterator, which allow for `memcpy(&(*begin), ..., len);` to be used by the implementation

Comment: If you want to rely on memcpy then why not simply use a pointer instead? That's more something one would expect in C++. If you just want to provide a specialization for ContiguousIterator that allows better performance I'd still go with begin and end iterator and not a length, then one could also pass something like `dyn.begin()+5, dyn.end()` without having to substract the begin offset from the length

Answer (score 0):

I think when designing lib's interface you need to take in considiration where it will be used.

Library with C interface with "char *" can be used with wide variety of languages (C, C++ and others ). Using std::array limits your lib's potentional clients.

The third possible variant:

```
struct buf_f allocBuf();

int rmBuf( struct buf_t b );

int read( struct buf_f b );

char * bufData( struct buf_f b );

size_t bufSize( struct buf_f b );
```

Surely it can be rewritten with C++ in more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use make a wrapper function that is a template function that delegates to the C-interface function:

```
int read(std::uint8_t* buf, size_t len);

template <size_t N>
int read(std::array<std::uint8_t, N>& buf)
{
  return read(buf.data(), buf.size());
}
```

I've found such constructs useful when I need to something over an C ABI but didn't want to lose some of the comforts that C++ gives to, as the template function is compiled as part of the library client code and doesn't need to be C ABI compatible while thee function the template function call is C ABI compatible

Answer (score -3):

Just return a `std::vector<uint8_t>`, unless this is a DLL, in which case go with a C style interface.

<sup><sub>Note: answer changed from `std::string` to `std::vector` after change of question from `char` to `uint8_t`.</sub></sup>

Comment: There is nothing in the question to suggest the buffers contain strings. It may be binary data that, while `std::string` may be able to store them, is better represented by other containers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: `std::string` is well suited for any byte sequence. It is so used by Google. "better represented by other containers" is an opinion I wouldn't give much credence to without supporting evidence, given that you failed to notice the plain `char` type here.

Comment: I'm not anonymous. I don't recognize using `std::string` as *"the only up-front reasonable design"* nor do I recognize it as *" the currently accepted best practice"*. `std::string` is usually expected to contain displayable character data. And while that's not formally required, it's a nasty surprise for anyone not familiar with it. Perhaps it works well in your environment but I disagree that it should be recommended as a general solution to this problem, thus the downvote. I *do* see how SSO might be useful, but I consider using  `std::vector<char>` instead makes the intention much clearer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: First of all `std::string` is used this way in several binary interfaces, e.g. [Google protocol buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373325/google-protocol-buffers-and-use-of-stdstring-for-arbitrary-binary-data) (I just googled that). Secondly, the OP has vaguely indicated text (via `char` in modern C++), and not mentioned anything about binary. Oh, there's [a tool usage argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47537044/464581) in favor of `std::string`. And ditto conversion argument. Why not be practical?

Comment: Oh, now the OP has changed the question.

Comment: Is it ok to return a `std::vector` by copy ?

Comment: @boutboutnico: Yes, all standard containers can be returned by copy. In many cases that will not cause actual copying, but just a logical copy, because move semantics kicks in, and/or because of Return Value Optimization.

Comment: No I was afraid about copying it but C++11 guarantee it will be moved.