# std::string or std::vector<char> to hold raw data

Tags: c++, string

I hope this question is appropriate for stackoverflow... What is the difference between storing raw data bytes (8 bits) in a `std::string` rather than storing them in `std::vector<char>`. I'm reading binary data from a file and storing those raw bytes in a `std::string`. This works well, there are no problems or issues with doing this. My program works as expected. However, other programmers prefer the `std::vector<char>` approach and suggest I stop using `std::string` as it's unsafe for raw bytes. So I'm wondering why might it be unsafe to use `std::string` to hold raw data bytes? I know `std::string` is most often used to store ASCII text, but a byte is a byte, so I don't understand the preference of the `std::vector<char>`.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It used to be that std::string was not guaranteed to provide contiguous storage, which matters if you do things like `&s[0]` to obtain a non-const pointer to data. But this is no longer true as of C++11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vector <unsigned char> vs string for binary data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556229/vector-unsigned-char-vs-string-for-binary-data)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not really whether it works or it doesn't. The problem is that it is utterly confusing for the next guy reading your code. `std::string` is meant for displaying text. Anybody reading your code will expect that. You'll declare your *intent* much better with a `std::vector<char>`.

It increases your [WTF/min](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m) in code reviews.

Comment: I've never thought of it that way. Good point. I think of std::string as a container holding bytes. They may be ASCII bytes, but are not required to be. In my mind, std::string is std::bytes, but it's good to know that others think differently. I can see how this would be confusing.

Comment: For more points of view, when I think "byte", I think `uint8_t`. For the most part, I only use `char` when I'm actually holding *character* data, when I'm using buffers (e.g. using `new char[]` to allocate the memory in which I'm going to construct an object), or to play nice with some established API that uses `char`. I would generally prefer to have have a `std::vector<uint8_t>` to store raw byte data.

Comment: @Hurkyl `uint8_t` is _not_ guaranteed to be one byte long. `char` is.

Comment: @zenith: It would be interesting to know the loophole that lets that work; I know `CHAR_BIT` has to be at least `8`, and sizes of objects have to be in multiples of a byte. The path to `uint8_t` not existing is clear; how do you arrange for it to *exist* and with `sizeof(uint8_t) > 1`?

Answer (score 6):

In C++03, using `std::string` to store an array of byte data was not a good idea. By the standard, `std::string` did not *have* to store data contiguously. C++11 fixed that so that it's data does have to be contiguous.

So it would not be functional to do this in C++03. Not unless you have personally vetted your C++ standard library implementation of `std::string` to ensure that it is contiguous.

Either way, I would suggest `vector<char>`. Generally, when you see `string`, you expect it to be a... string. You know, a sequence of characters in some form of encoding. A `vector<char>` makes it obvious that it isn't a string, but an array of bytes.

Comment: Thank you. We use C++11 so the bytes are contiguous. My idea of std::string seems to be broader than most. I appreciate your opinion. It's good for me to understand why others find this confusing, even though it works.

Answer (score 3):

Besides contiguous storage and code-clarity issues, I ran into some fairly insidious errors trying to use `std::string` to hold raw bytes.

Most of them centered around trying to convert a `char` array of bytes to `std::string` when interfacing with C libraries. For example:

```
std::string password = "pass\0word";
std::cout << password.length() << std::endl; // prints 4, not 9
```

Maybe you can fix that by specifying the length:

```
std::string password("pass\0word", 0, 9);
std::cout << password.length() << std::endl; // nope! still 4!
```

This is probably because the constructor expects to receive a C-string, not a byte array. There might be a better way, but I ended up with this:

```
std::string password("pass0word", 0, 9);
password[4] = '\0';
std::cout << password.length() << std::endl; // hurray! 9!
```

A little clunky. Thankfully I found this in unit testing, but I would have missed it if my test vectors didn't have null bytes. What makes this insidious is that the second approach above will work fine *until* the array contains a null byte.

So far `std::vector<uint8_t>` looks like a good option (thanks J.N. and Hurkyl):

```
char p[] = "pass\0word";
std::vector<uint8_t> password(p, p, p+9); // :)
```

Note: I haven't tried the iterator constructor with `std::string`, but this error is easy enough to make that it might be worth avoiding even the possibility.

Lessons learned:

- Test byte-handling methods witih null byte-containing test vectors.
- Be careful when (and I would say avoid) using `std::string` to hold raw bytes.

Comment: Can you initialize a vector of `char` or `uint8_t` from a string literal in C++11?

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string` to store characters from text files. That way you can be rest assured that character encoding is done properly for you.

Use `std::vector<std::byte>` to store raw bytes from binary files. This will prevent unintended type conversions and ensure safe data manipulation. The exact representation of the data is crucial and intent is communicated.