# Which is better datatype to store binary data string or vector of char in c++

Tags: c++, binary-data

I have been working in a project to upload and download binary data, i have done uploading and downloading using binary data by storing them in string, but some says binary data should be stored in vector of char than string. I don't exactly find the proper reason for using vector of char over string. I tested my code for uploading and downloading pdf, image, audio, video files everything works fine with string.

Please guide me which is the better datatype to store binary data and what are the reasons?

Comment: On second thought, I like the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556229/vector-unsigned-char-vs-string-for-binary-data better.

Comment: @jamesdlin I've included your second suggestion in the close vote now.

Comment: sorry for the duplication and thanks for notifying