# representing BLOBs in C++

Tags: c++, stl, blob

Are there any STL containers that seem to be well-suited for using as BLOBs for database software? I would think a `vector<char>`, but is there something better? Maybe a `std::string`? Or some non-STL container?

Comment: Well, is it a text string? If not (as a BLOB is just a bunch of binary rubbish), then a `std::string` is a bad idea. In the same sense is vector of a `char`s (which are text characters) a bad idea, compared to a vector of `unsigned char`s.

Comment: @ChristianRau: `char` is not a "text character". `string` is not a bad idea.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, conceptually it is. And conceptually a string is a bad idea for non-text. Conceptually, of course.

Comment: @ChristianRau: No. Conceptually, a `char` is the smallest addressable unit of data, and the basic unit of I/O. Thus it is in fact the perfect type to represent arbitrary data. The only thing wrong with `char` is its own name.

Comment: @KerrekSB Then is there no difference between `char` and `unsigned char` when not used for numbers?

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, I would prefer a type with a definite specified (over multiple platforms) signedness, considering that binary data is often best manipulated as a sequence of integer numbers. Though you're right in that if you don't manipulate it (as it may be the case for a BLOB), an undefinite signedness may suffice. But I just have an objection against unspecified signedness and for ma a `char` is a character, may just be something subjective without reason.

Comment: That's how BLOBS are handled in OTL - http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_lob_stream.htm

Comment: @baruch: `signed char` and `unsigned char` are arithmetic, integral types just like `int` and `unsigned int`. On the other hand, `char` is expressly intended to be the "I/O" type that represents some opaque, system-specific fundamental unit of data on your platform. I would use them in this spirit.

Comment: @KerrekSB But Ok, even if `char` is best used for binary data (which you seem to be right with), `std::string` definitely isn't, as it is conceptually a text-string. You don't want to use any locale-based comparisons and transformations for binary data, let aside NUL-termination.

Comment: @bobah What is? chars, unsigned chars, vectors, strings?

Comment: @baruch, that particular example was with stream, this is a link to the full examples list http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_examples.htm, I suggested looking at it because OTL is a single header, and if you find an example that matches your use case you can check the source code underneath and do the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `BLOB` type of databases allows storage of binary data, so you need an ordered collection of bytes.  The easiest choice would be a `vector<>` and you could chose `unsigned char` to represent a byte on most platforms

Answer (score 2):

We have used `stream`s in one of our projects to represent BLOB/CLOB values stored in the database. I think this is most of the time the best approach, as BLOB/CLOBs could be really large to fit in memory by definition.

Write a `stream` implementation of your own and use it just like any other `stream`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using `std::string` to store blobs, since I'm using Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) library for object serialization, and that's what they use (e.g., [MessageLite::SerializeToString](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.SerializeToString)). It works well for my purposes since inserting the resulting string as a blob into an SQLite database is very straightforward:

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(_insert_statement, 3, data.c_str(), data.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
```

(`data` is a `std::string` being bound as the third argument to `_insert_statement`.)

Comment: How do you populate the string?

Comment: Take a look at the [Protocol Buffers example](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview); instead of `person.SerializeToOstream(&output)` I use `person.SerializeAsString()` and then use the result as an SQLite blob. There's also `SerializeToString(std::string*)` if you really want to avoid copying.