# Using cout with basic_string<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, cout

cout works with string (a.k.a. `basic_string<char>`) and all number types (`int`, `char`, `unsigned char`, `double`, etc.). However it cannot handle `basic_string<unsigned char>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::basic_string<unsigned char> zzz(3, 'z');
    std::cout << zzz << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile with

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::basic_string<unsigned char>')
```

I would expect this to behave the same way as string. Is there a reason why ostream doesn't handle `std::basic_string<unsigned char>`?

Comment: Relevant overloads: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Comment: Maybe what you want are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/277684/4015174)

Answer (score 2):

The standard defines the following template operator:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, 
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

This means you can stream `std::string` to `std::cout`, and `std::wstring` to `std::wcout`.  You can't stream `std::wstring` to `std::cout`.

Your problem is that `std::cout` uses character type `char`, not `unsigned char`.

You can define an additional operator in the global namespace if you like.

```
typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const ustring& str) {
    if (const auto len = str.size())
       stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&str[0]), len);
    return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no matching `std::ostream` overload for it in the standard library. You can however, provide your own overload. *Though you may have different behavior for characters that aren't [`std::isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint)*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::basic_string<unsigned char>& str){
    for(auto ch : str)
        os << static_cast<char>(ch);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::basic_string<unsigned char> zzz(3, 'z');
    std::cout << zzz << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
zzz
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2457bb299b6ae269)

Answer (score 1):

The global object [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is of type [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) which is an alias for `std::basic_ostream<char>`. The relevant operator is [`std::basic_string::operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) which requires that the `std::basic_string<CharT>` and the `std::basic_ostream<CharT>` share the same type `CharT`. In your example, you are using `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` and `std::basic_ostream<char>` which is not supported, since `unsigned char` and `char` are distinct types. Note that `signed char` and `unsigned char` are always distinct from `char`.

> char - type for character representation which can be most efficiently processed on the target system (has the same representation and alignment as either signed char or unsigned char, but is always a distinct type). [...] [Link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Answer (score 1):

Like with, say, a `std::vector<char>`, there's no obvious "default" behaviour here, so it's not provided out of the box. It *can* work; you'll just have to define *how* it works yourself.